Primefaces Datatable: how to default select a checkbox which is disabled
I have a datatable and a particular row's checkbox is disabled. But it is not showing as selected.
I want to show it as selected by default though it is disabled default.
Please help me how to do that.
If I remove the below from dataTable, then its selected by default, but of course its not disabled.
disabledSelection="#{value == 'AAA'}"
I verified the value in selectedArray. It is present even the row is disabled.
selection="#{bean.selectedArray}"

I assume you are using PrimeFaces 14?  This was done on purpose: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/11356
Basically if a row is marked as disabled the component does not respect its checked/unchecked value as its disabled and should be completely ignored by the server side.

Thanks for the details. I am using Prime faces 8. Is it the same with 8.0 as well?

No that might be a bug in 8.0 that has LONG since been fixed.  8.0 is no longer supported by the community so you won't have any luck getting a bug fix.
